# Trying to find if a value is below a certain criteria for a specified duration within a time period window with timeseries data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I am working with Timescale timeseries_data and I am returning a result of

```
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:58:22.320738 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>41.0}
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:58:22.315896 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>41.0}
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:48:22.319072 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>40.0}
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:48:22.314071 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>40.0}
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:33:22.317477 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>39.0}
{"sensor_id"=>41, "ts"=>2021-12-22 18:33:22.30453 +0000, "std_name"=>"CW", "plant_id"=>139, "value"=>39.0}
```

I am trying to come up with a sql query where for within the last 89 minutes there is any 30 minute period where value is less than 40 or some arbitrary number.  I am working in rails and I think I can come up with a rails solution, but I don't think it would be the cleanest.

Comment: By less than 40, what do you mean? The average? Or a 30 minute period where no value is less than 30?

Comment: Also - what resolution for the window? For example, are you only considering minute by minute (e.g. 18:30:00 to 19:00:00 and then 18:31:00 to 19:01:00) or each second or continuous (e.g. a window of 18:58:22.315896 to 19:28:22.315896)

Comment: all values in the thirty minute window are less than 40.  and All values in any thirty minute window within the 89 minute window including values with seconds

Comment: Sounds good - can you add detail for what you've tried or attempted so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: In case it's useful there is some YouTube content on using Rails with TimescaleDB this is one of them https://youtu.be/hGPsUxLFAYk (apologies I don't have the answer but noticed that you were considering rails...) 

Transparency: I work for Timescale

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I fully understand your question, but, it seems like, from the comments that you'll need to use a window function, something like:

```
SELECT 
sensor_id,
ts,
max(value) OVER prev_30, -- gets the max value over the previous 30 mins 
max(value) OVER prev_30 < 40 -- your filter potentially? 
FROM your_table
WINDOW prev_30 AS (PARTITION BY sensor_id ORDER BY ts ASC RANGE '30 min' PRECEDING)
```

I hope that helps with what you're wondering, Miranda and I also just recorded some videos on window functions that might help you... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFv9cVZbs50 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xJUIiHHxvI